# Three.js - how to access animation clip control when raycasting an object

Tags: json, three.js, raycasting

I have been playing with `three.js` a little bit now but could find a way to sort this out.
Basically, I have a raycast function, so when I click on an object, the color change to red.

Those object are all imported thanks to JSON loader and what I would like to do is to control the animation of those object. For Instance, I would like those to start playing when I click on it.

I though I could do something like but this doesn't work.

`intersects[0].clipAction(geometry.animations[0]).setDuration(4).play()`

Comment: Can you show more of your code? How are `intersects` and `geometry` defined? Are you sure `intersects[0]` is a [THREE.AnimationMixer](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/animation/AnimationMixer)? And, in what way does your code "not work"? Do you see any errors in the console?